# How to create an app for website integration: Javascript API

Tags: facebook, web, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm a bit confused on how to implement the javascript api on my website. First, I need to create an app from facebook, but are there any settings that I should pay more attention to?

Ultimately, I Just want a like button - but I have elements on the page that will pay attention to the like stats, and would like to subscribe to the Edge.create etc methods.

I have an 'App for websites' created, but I'm running into a few issues: First, my like button doesn't show up at all unless the user is logged in. The second is that I just want it to say 'Greg likes biscuitcleaver.com' (much like it would read if the user liked a facebook page - but instead, when I click the like button it says 'Greg Likes a page on biscuitcleaver.com'

Ultimately, the link that ends up on Facebook should just redirect back to my url that I have registered with the Like button.  (oh by the way, the url that's in the like button - does it have to be registered with my app somewhere @ developers.facebook.com/apps)?

Thanks!
-Greg

Comment: You need to implement a `website` object in the Open Graph meta tags at the root of the domain, where the button is. Read about it here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have a look at the FB [Javascript SD](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/)K and its [login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/getting-started/#sample) use case for examples and all the configuration details. Beware that FB has been known to change the behavoir of their SDK, so what's true about it today might not be by short notice.

Comment: I was in a weird condition, it turned out. I was on one page, but the like button was pointing to another. There are a lot of 'gotchas' that had me spinning my wheels.